# Git-Jenkins integration error while configuring

Tags: git, jenkins, devops

What should be a solution for the below error for Jenkins ?
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: git.exe ls-remote -h

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the rest of the error message, as well as the URL used.

Jenkins will run under a dedicated account (sometimes, on Windows, under the System account).
You will need to check if that account has the right to access the remote repository, either through:

- HTTPS credentials (username/password), as cached locally by a `git config credential.helper` (again, as used by the account running Jenkins master)
- or SSH (possibly passphrase cached by an SSH agent), accessing the rigth `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa` private key: make sure the running account does have access to the private key.

Answer (score 1):

In Global Tool Configuration of Jenkins, set the Path to Git executable